# What is the notation for alternating series with "$\cdots$"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I know that the notation isn't very important, but I am curious. If I have the following alternating series:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}
$$
Which of the following notations is the most correct (or the best) for represent the previous series?

> \begin{align}
> &\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\cdots \tag{1} \\[6pt]
> &\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\cdots \tag{2} \\[6pt]
> &\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}\pm\cdots \tag{3} \\[6pt]
> &\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+-\cdots \tag{4} \\[6pt]
> &\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}\cdots \tag{5} \\
> \end{align}

I think that is the equation $(3)$, but I am not sure.

Comment: The best is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$. But of the rest, I'd prefer (2).

Comment: I also prefer (2). I've never seen (3) or (4).

Comment: 2 is best. Also the singular of "series" is oddly enough "series" not "serie" which isn't a word.

Comment: I second the above comments. Ellipses are for hiding part of a sentence, so I would also go for (2).

Comment: I go for $(2)$!

Comment: @ZacharySelk thank you for the correction

Comment: Would go for $(2)$. Another contender:$$\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}\cdots$$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I added that to the question, thank you

Comment: 2 is most common. (See, for instance, some examples in Wikipedia's ["Taylor series" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).) So long as you've included enough terms to establish the pattern, you're fine. In cases where the pattern isn't entirely clear, the sigma notation is best; alternatively, you can write $$\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\cdots + \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} + \cdots$$

Comment: @Blue That could be a good and interesant answer

Comment: One positive reason to use convention (2): the alternating series error estimate. If it's specifically a series of terms of decreasing absolute value, the sign of the error in a partial sum - what we would need to add to get the infinite sum - is the same as the sign of the next term. So, in this common case, that trailing $+$ or $-$ sign can be used to indicate what direction we're off in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a comment to an answer ...

---

(2) is most common. (See, for instance, some examples in Wikipedia's ["Taylor series" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).) So long as you've included enough terms to establish the pattern, you're fine. In cases where the pattern may not be entirely clear, the sigma notation is best; alternatively, you can provide this hybrid form
$$\frac{1}{0!}−\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}−\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}−\cdots+\frac{(−1)^n}{n!}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 5):

I would use  $(5)$ or maybe $(2)$, but I don't think it is very important.  What is important is to show enough terms that the pattern is obvious.  I would not rely on the trailing sign to convey that information, which is why I would use $(5)$.  I think $(5)$ is sufficient, but I might show the next term before I went to dots.

Comment: +1 If understanding the pattern comes down to the character before trailing ellipsis, then you either haven't demonstrated the pattern well enough, or (more likely) you should find a more precise way to express it.

Comment: This is a very good answer, thank you for your knowledge